# How to keep a process freezed until I unfreeze it?

Tags: windows, process-explorer

Is there any way to freeze a process, which should not run again until I unfreeze it, even if the system is restarted?

The 'Greenify' app can do this for Android. Is there a similar solution for Windows?

As a workaround, what I am doing currently is to see the process location in "process explorer" and rename that exe to something else, so that it can not be called again.

But I know this is a very raw workaround. Is there any better way?

Comment: I think you want something like Faronics WinSelect

Comment: Does Winselect helps me to select and process and freeze or make it not work unless i unlock it?

Comment: That's exactly what WinSelect is for. It locks down access to certain applications unless a password is provided.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do not want to lock the whole app but may be one or two processes of it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

For immediate suspension to ensure you're not pausing something that destabilizes your system, [PsSuspend](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx) from Microsoft SysInternals.

To prevent typically automatic things from running, Start | Run | msconfig. An article on startup program management is at the [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/).

You could also edit the ACL (permissions) of the target EXE and prevent your unprivileged user from executing it. This may be safer than renaming it, because you can login as administrator and still access the file as intended. It may be a special permission (from Advanced permissions rather than top-level) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/258365/246220) may assist.